# Trying to zip header and main body of data into dict to reference data by column names

Tags: python

I am trying to zip that headerLine data, which is composed of the column names, and the mainBody of the data into a dict in which I can reference the data by column names.

I have been trying to do something like this but i just can't make it work:

```
for col in mainBody:
    valueList = col.split(',')
    for i in range(len(valueList)):
        d = dict(zip(headerLine, valueList[0:]))
```

Here is the rest of the code for the program:

```
def array_setter():
    import os
    import glob
    import pprint
    direct = os.chdir\
    ('/Users/thomaswolff/Documents/Data Exports/north_south_data_exports')
    for file in glob.glob('*.TXT'):
        reader = open(file)
        headerLine = reader.readline()
        mainBody = reader.readlines()
        for col in mainBody:
             valueList = col.split(',')
             for i in range(len(valueList)):
                  d = dict(zip(headerLine, valueList[i]))
                  data[i] = [d[col] for col in headerLine]
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? What results are you expecting, and what results do you actually get? Some example inputs and outputs would help...

Comment: Well the input is a huge comma-seperated text file. I need to reference by name since the input file is so large, about 240,000 rows by 51 columns. Far too many to use column indexing. I have been using indexing and the program works fine but its becoming a mess with all those index references. I'll explain the output next comment.

Comment: why are you not using the `csv` module?

Comment: Right now the is a key error: data[i] = [d[col] for col in headerLine]
KeyError: 'I'

Comment: Well would that work? The problem is the input is all data type string.

Comment: `csv.DictReader` does what you want.

Comment: csv stands for comma separated values, it has nothing to do with Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to thebjorn for the suggestion to use .csvDictReader that has worked out great. Also thanks to gboffi for the code. It worked pretty well but I was able to get the dictreader to do exactly what I needed. Here is the resultant code:

```
def data_parser():
import glob
import csv
for file in glob.glob('*.TXT'):
    with open(file, 'rb') as file_data:
        data_set = []
        reader = csv.DictReader(file_data)
        for i in reader:
            data_set.append(i)
        for row in data_set:
            date = str(row['DATE'])
            route = str(row['ROUTE'])
            lane = int(row['LANE'])
            from_ = float(row['FROM'])
            to = float(row['TO'])
            iriLeft = int(row['IRI_1'])
            iriRight = int(row['IRI_2'])
            avg_iri = int(row['AVG_IRI'])

            yield date,route,from_,to,iriLeft,iriRight
data_parser()

def data_sep():
    import pprint
    generator_1 = data_parser()
    for row in generator_1:
        pprint.pprint(row)
data_sep()
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done on the command line

```
% cat test2.csv
Roll_num Marks Grade
1        75    A
2        60    C
27       68    B
61       45    E
% python -c "print {c[0]:list(c[1:]) for c in zip(*[row.strip().split() for row in open('test2.csv')])}"
{'Grade': ['A', 'C', 'B', 'E'], 'Roll_num': ['1', '2', '27', '61'], 'Marks': ['75', '60', '68', '45']}
%
```

but in a more sensible manner you can put it into a source file like this...

```
f = open('test2.csv')
raw_data = [row.strip().split() for row in f]
data = {col[0]:list(col[1:]) for col in zip(*raw_data)}
```

The details of what you do to process file contents into raw data may differ in your particular case but the list comprehension on some variation of `row.strip().split()` is rather idiomatic, as well the use of `zip(*stuff)` to transpose the elements of a list of lists.

Comment: Well i tried that method gboffi but my work computer (which admittedly isn't much) got pretty hung up running the program. Also, it only printed the first five columns.